# Is it possible to exclude auto-generated files when importing classes from one C# project to another?

Tags: c#, grpc

Is it possible to exclude auto-generated files when importing classes from one C# project to another?

I have one project that implements a GRPC service based on classes generated from the proto file.

Also, I have another project where I test classes of the first project like GRPC service. In the second project, I implemented a GRPC client to test the GRPC service with the same copy of the proto file.

The problem is that I import all classes of the first project and sorrowfully some of them are generated with the same proto file and there are a lot of warnings about class names collisions.

Is there a way to import only specific files between projects of the same solution?

I use the next directives in project files to generate classes:

- In the first project:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Protobuf Include="Protos\Proto.proto" GrpcServices="Server" />
</ItemGroup>
```

- In the second one:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Protobuf Include="Protos\Proto.proto" GrpcServices="Client" />
</ItemGroup>
```

And I import classes of the first project to the second one like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\core\First.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>
```

And the warnings are like this:

```
TestClient.cs(53,29): warning CS0436: The type 'Type1' in '/folder1/solution/test_project/obj/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/Class1.cs' conflicts with the imported type 'Type1' in 'Project1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Using the type defined in '/folder1/solutiion/test/obj/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/Class1.cs'. [/folder1/solution/test_project/Project2.csproj]
```

Comment: Is this tied to `Visual Studio 2017/2019` ?

Comment: No, I use .Net Core 3.1's `dotnet` to build it in CLI with Linux Ubuntu 19.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't conditionally import the types, but you can add an [extern alias](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/extern-alias) to the types in your First project when importing it to the second project.

Add the following snippet to your second .csproj

```
  <Target Name="ChangeAliasesOfStrongNameAssemblies" BeforeTargets="FindReferenceAssembliesForReferences;ResolveReferences">
    <ItemGroup>
      <ReferencePath Condition="'%(FileName)' == 'First'">
        <Aliases>FirstExtern</Aliases>
      </ReferencePath>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

you can now explicitly define which type you want to use:
add this above all the usings in your .cs code:

```
extern alias FirstExtern;
```

and reference the types from the first project by specifying the defined alias:

```
FirstExtern::First.Type1 variable;
```

Answer (score 3):

I usually create my proto files and their resulting generated code in a single assembly, then reference that assembly from the service and the client assemblies.  This keeps the code generated once, and eliminates the duplicated code generation.